# Why does a grep reboot the machine?

Tags: files, grep, directory-structure

On a RHEL 6.5 Desktop, if I use:

```
sudo grep -r foo /*
```

my desktop reboots.

**Q:** Why?? How to debug this? It's the third time my Desktop reboots because of this :D

Comment: Because you shouldn't do this. By greping the root, you may read a file in `/proc` or `/sys` which initiates the system reboot.

Comment: Absolutly no idea. You can try `sudo grep -r foo /* > /root/grep.log` and may find some additional info...

Comment: @Spack I can't imagine there's a proc file that reboots on *read*.

Comment: By the way, why did you do this (three times)?

Comment: @Tobias : Why not? It is pretty weird and worth investigating.  Contra Spack, I think you should be able to `grep -r` the entire filesystem safely.

Comment: I just wundered if there is a good reason for it. I must confess, I also like to try such things. And I also think, this shoud work without reboot.

Comment: And maybe `strace` would print some interesting infos...

Comment: Magic of escape sequences at work!

Comment: How does it reboot? Is it a clean `init 6` or does the screen just go black and the machine reboots?

Comment: strace helped, please post it as answer, the bad device was the /dev/cdrom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strace helped, the bad device was the /dev/cdrom

Comment: wow!! my machine is rebooting, and I need to find the source of that problem too!!! http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/172396/how-does-auto-reboot-happens

Answer (score 7):

There are things you're not supposed to blindly read from.

`/dev/mem` and `/dev/kmem` come to mind, but [`/dev/port`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/mem.4.html) sounds even more dangeous to read - it maps to I/O ports directly. Reading blindly from that sounds like a recipe for disaster (hard-locked my machine a few minutes ago... for science I guess). I don't think reading from that file will result in the same symptoms for all machines, but a reboot doesn't sound unreasonable.

At the very least, you should exclude `/dev` entirely from that, and `/sys` and `/proc` shouldn't be included either - it makes no sense to search those filesystems even if it was entirely safe.

Consider the performance as well. Do you really want to grep all of `/dev/sda`, then all of `/dev/sda1`, then whatever filesystem contents it has (assuming it's mounted)?

Comment: Since version 2.12, GNU grep only searches in regular files (or special files passed on the command line) when invoked with `-r`. But RHEL6 has version 2.6.3 which indeed searches in all files including devices.

Comment: `/proc/kcore` would be another. And that one appears as a completely normal file. It even has a size on it.