# How does auto reboot happen?

Tags: reboot

For no apparent reason, my machine is rebooting.

`last reboot` brings lines like this:

```
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Tue Dec  9 18:57 - 19:09  (00:11)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Tue Dec  9 12:59 - 19:09  (06:09)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Tue Dec  9 11:07 - 11:35  (00:28)    
reboot   system boot  3.13.0-24-generi Mon Dec  8 13:52 - 01:20  (11:27)
```

With the [pseudo-user reboot](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7760/output-of-the-last-command).

I need to know:

- **who is calling/activating this pseudo-user *reboot*?**
- **why(how to track it)?**
- and how to fix/prevent that? (I may have to answer this one myself after I discover what is happening)

I am still researching, but my machine may suddenly reboot, so I have to post now!

related: [Why does a grep reboot the machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126320/why-does-a-grep-reboot-the-machine), about IO problems
related: [about full memory](https://askubuntu.com/questions/488037/random-crashes-ubuntu-12-04)

After two weeks my machine still reboots for no reason. I wonder if anyone has any idea of what "things" should not be accessed? I mean: are there places in `/proc` or `/dev` where we should avoid performing too many reads or writes? Or some commands that we should avoid? Do `xdotool` or `wmctrl` have some specific commands that should be avoided like trying to command a closed window id or something like that? any idea?

**Narrowing it Down**
My machine seems to not reboot if I keep some scripts stopped.

I am trying to narrow down what can cause this; I think a script I have may be the source; it, along with others, runs commands like these:

```
windowId=`xdotool getactivewindow`
xdotool getwindowname $windowId
xdotool search --sync "^Desktop$"
wmctrl -d
wmctrl -i -r $windowId -b toggle,maximized_vert,maximized_horz
xwininfo -wm -id $lnWindowId
```

Not exactly in this order, but basically they are all related to X window manipulations.
And, they happen very often, like 4 times each second;
And, they may happen on an unavailable window (that was just closed), or on some special windows like [conky clock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/550154/how-to-have-a-clock-indicator-highly-visible) one, or in any non standard "window" (that is not a window like the unity hud).

It seems X windows manipulation can cause reboot then?

Comment: It might be worth posting excerpts from ```/var/log/messages``` and your bash history from the time that the reboots were happening. Is this a desktop or a server?

Comment: It is a desktop, but I have like 11 bash scripts running simultaneously on misc tasks, but they are like that for about a year or so. I will check that messages.

Comment: Nobody calls or activates the user. It's just how a reboot is logged in the records that `last` uses, no matter what triggered the reboot.

Comment: @Dayvo the reboot happened around 18:33, may be 18:32:30 (I got stunned), on log there was this: _"Dec  9 18:30:39 hostid wpa_supplicant[1226]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-SCAN-STARTED"_, and this _"Dec  9 18:31:35 hostid postfix/sendmail[3555097]: fatal: open /etc/postfix/main.cf: No such file or directory"_, but these last ones happen very often and they were much before the reboot time.

Comment: @muru, any tip on how to catch what triggered the reboot?

Comment: Can you grep for `shutdown` in the various log files in `/var/log` as a first step? The exact files varies based on distribution (I don't have a `messages`, for example).

Comment: @muru, here is `/var/log/syslog` also. But anyway, at /var/log, this `grep shutdown * -irn 2>/dev/null` only showed wtmp (but that is what we read at `last`)